# Opening any text file

Tags: c++

Is this the correct way to open any text file? This is a small section of the code im using. I keep getting an error message when trying to open a file through putty.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
string a;
a = argv[1];
//a = a + ".txt";
ifstream fin;
fin.open(a);
}
```

- x.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
- x.cpp:1225:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream::open(std::string&)’

  fin.open(a);
- x.cpp:1225:12: note: candidate is:
  In file included from x.cpp:7:0:
  /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:538:7: note: void std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]

  open(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in)
- /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/fstream:538:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’ to ‘const char*’

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with putty, you need to fix your errors first. To start off, `argv[1]` isn't a `string`, it's a `char *`.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the program argument directly to `fin.open`, you don't need to convert to a `string` first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(argv[1]);

    string line;
    if (fin.is_open()) {
        getline(fin, line);
        cout << line << '\n';
    }

    fin.close();
}
```